# Why `strncmp()` return a fault value in a special case?

Tags: c, string, c-strings, strncmp

I wrote a small code piece of code in C to test `strncmp()`, `memcmp()` functions. Here is the code.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    const char s1[] = "abcd\0\0\0\0";
    const char s2[] = "abcd\0abc";
    
    printf("strncmp(s1, s2, 4) = %d\n", strncmp(s1, s2, 5)); //0
    printf("strncmp(s1, s2, 8) = %d\n", strncmp(s1, s2, 8)); // why returns 0? Thx
    printf("memcmp(s1, s2, 4) = %d\n", memcmp(s1, s2, 5)); // 0
    printf("memcmp(s1, s2, 8) = %d\n", memcmp(s1, s2, 8)); // -120

    return 0;
}
```

I found `strncmp(s1, s2, 8) = 0` while `memcmp(s1, s2, 8) = -97`. Because `\0` is not equal to `a`, I think `strncmp(s1, s2, 8)` should return a non-zero value.

Then I tried to print `s1` and `s2` lengths, both of them are 9. And I tried to test more cases, `strncmp()` works as expected.

Finally, I tried a similar case as `s1` and `s2`, `strncmp` returns a fault value. The following is my code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    const char s1[] = "abcd\0\0\0\0";
    const char s2[] = "abcd\0xyz";
    
    printf("strncmp(s1, s2, 4) = %d\n", strncmp(s1, s2, 5)); //0
    printf("strncmp(s1, s2, 8) = %d\n", strncmp(s1, s2, 8)); // why returns 0? Thx
    printf("memcmp(s1, s2, 4) = %d\n", memcmp(s1, s2, 5)); // 0
    printf("memcmp(s1, s2, 8) = %d\n", memcmp(s1, s2, 8)); // -120

    printf("sizeof(s1) = %lu\n", sizeof(s1)); // 9
    printf("sizeof(s2) = %lu\n", sizeof(s2)); // 9

    printf("%d\n", strncmp("\0", "a", 1)); // -1
    printf("%d\n", strncmp("\0\0", "ab", 2)); // -1
    printf("%d\n", strncmp("a\0", "ab", 2)); // -1

    printf("%d\n", strncmp("a\0\0", "a\0b", 3)); // 0, why?

    return 0;
}
```

I guess maybe `strncmp()` will not compare characters after it meets `\0`? Isn't that how `strcmp` works. I'm not sure that `strncmp()` works like `strcmp()`.

Answer (score 4):

Per the man pages, your suspicion is correct:

> Because strncmp() is designed for comparing strings rather than binary
> data, characters that appear after a `\0' character are not compared.

Concatenating two null-terminated strings as a single string with two null characters will only result in the first portion being displayed.

Comment: Thanks. Can you provide the manual page link? I read `strncmp()` manual page before asking, but I didn't find your quoted sentence in my local computer manual. It just tells me that "the strncmp() function is similar, except it compares only the first (at most) n bytes of s1 and s2".

Answer (score 1):

> *I guess maybe `strncmp()` will not compare characters after it meets `\0`?*

Yes, this is correct.

> *Isn't that how `strcmp` works. I'm not sure that `strncmp()` works like `strcmp()`.*

`strcmp()` compares two null-terminated byte string.

`strncmp()` compares not more than `count` characters (characters that follow a null character are not compared) *[where `count` is the third argument passed to `strncmp()`]*.

For e.g.:

```
    const char s1[] = "abcd\0\0\0\0";
    const char s2[] = "abcd\0xyz";
```

The following statements will do exactly same comparison i.e. both will compare first `5` characters and return the result `0` (contents of both the strings are same) because the first `5` characters in both the string is same and `5`<sup>th</sup> character is null character (`\0`):

```
    strncmp (s1, s2, 8);
    strcmp (s1, s2);
```

`strncmp()` will produce same result for the third argument value `7`, `6` and `5` passed  to it.

But consider following case:

```
    strncmp (s1, s2, 4); 
    strcmp (s1, s2);
```

In this case, though, both will return `0` (same strings) but the comparison performed by `strncmp()` and `strcmp()` is different. `strncmp()` will compare only first `4` characters, whereas, `strcmp()` will compare till it finds null character. Same for third argument value `3`, `2`, `1` and `0` passed to `strncmp()`.

Take another example:

```
    const char s1[] = "abcdef";
    const char s2[] = "abcde";
```

`strcmp (s1, s2)` will never return equal for these strings, but
`strncmp (s1, s2, 5 /*or 4/3/2/1/0 */)` will compare them equal.

Another point,

> *Then I tried to print s1 and s2 lengths, both of them are 9.*

Note that, `sizeof` does not give length but it gives the size of the object (or type) in bytes. If you want to calculate the length of a string, use `strlen()`.

---

Couple of points to remember:

1). `strncmp()` does not compare characters following the null character.

2). One of the main difference between `memcmp()` and `strncmp()` is that `strncmp()` honour<sup>1)</sup> the null character while doing comparison but `memcmp()` doesn't.

Comment: Thanks for your patient and clear answer :)